# JQuery .attr('disabled',true) not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I tried some methods in old questions but it is not working in chrome.

Can please any one suggest me the solution.i'm using php for validation.

if i click submit button twice it through an error so restrict the issue i disable the submit button but it not working in chrome.

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('#submit_button').click(function () {
    jQuery('#submit_button').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` i.e. `jQuery('#submit_button').prop('disabled',true);` or why not simple `this.disabled = true;`

Comment: Your code is working well, tested on Chrome. Please make sure you've imported jQuery libraries.

Comment: I missed some think in  question.After the disable in crome after that redirection is to perform that redirection is not performing in chrome

Comment: @RaghulRajendran  you are showing something and asking something else?from where the hell redirection comes into picture here?

Comment: So you might be disabled Javascripts on your browser?

Answer (score 5):

You could use prop jquery method, or just set the disabled attribute to `true`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
  //$(this).prop('disabled', true);
  this.disabled = true;
 })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="submit">submit</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be that there are multiple submit buttons on the page. You can try using this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#submit_button').click(function () {
    // It is best practice to use `true` instead of 
    // any true-y kind of value like non-empty string.
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', true);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$('selector').prop('disabled',true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try, using the `prop` of element and making the `attribute` true, using

`jQuery('selector').prop('disabled',true);`

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#submit_button').click(function () {
            jQuery('#submit_button').prop('disabled',true);
           });
    });
</script>
```

how i would add disabled:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('button').click(function () {
            $('<input type="button id="submit_button" disabled>').insertBefore(this);
            $(this).remove();
         });
 });
</script>
```

how i would change the button back to normal:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('button').click(function () {
            $('<input type="button id="submit_button" >').insertBefore(this);
            $(this).remove();
         });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ideas were given but the code seems working properly. Please make sure you imported the jQuery library.

The following code is the tested code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#button').click(function () {
        jQuery('#button').attr('disabled','disabled');
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" id="button" value="If you click on me, I will be disabled."/>

</body>
</html>
```